# Double bar plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I would like to have a double bar plot with `matplotlib`. This is my code:

```
width = 0.55   
ax2.set_xlim(0,len(partiteIndici)+width)
plt.ylim([0,100])
rects1 = ax2.bar(partiteIndici, distanze, width,align='center', color='blue', label='4-3-3 Modello')
rects2 = ax2.bar(partiteIndici, distanze2, width,align='center', color='red', label='Squadra X')
plt.xticks(index + width, partite)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But this is what I have:
[image]

I would like to have blue bars next to red bars, not overlapped. How can I get this working?

And why do I have the markers on the x bar shifted respect to bars?

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code: first, you get your bar plots overlapped because you plot them with the same values of `x`; you need to manually shift one plot to get it working your way, as per [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). Assuming `partiteIndici` is an array, change `rects2` line to

```
rects2 = ax2.bar(partiteIndici + width, distanze2, width,align='center', color='red', label='Squadra X')
```

This will get one of your plots shifted. As per ticks and labels, you have to put them to the same `x` points as bars; change `index` in `xticks` line to `partiteIndici`:

```
plt.xticks(partiteIndici + width, partite)
```